Flutter: Save File to Phone's Downloads Directory. Dart
Using Flutter, Dart,
I need a solution to download File() Which comes from this import 'dart:io';   in the user's phone inside the downloads directory.
It would be really kind of someone to write a static inside class Function.
I need the function to work for both ios and android.
class FileDownloadService {
   static Future<bool> downloadFile(File pickedFile, String fileName) {}
}

